# Custom data attribute not working

Tags: javascript, html, svg

http://codepen.io/eamo2020/pen/mVNZbJ

I have a custom attribute on a circle element in an svg image, I'm trying to read the value of `data-xPos` and use it to update the `cx` position but I'm unable to read the `data-xPos` value

html

```
<section class="map">
  <div class="image">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <image xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f3/World_map_blank_gmt.png" />

      <circle data-xPos="0.5" cx="0.5" cy="27" r="1.2" fill="#0f0" stroke="#0f0" stroke-width="2" stroke-opacity="0.4"/>

    </svg>
  </div>
</section>
```

js

```
width = document.getElementsByTagName("image")[0].parentNode.offsetWidth
var circles = document.getElementsByTagName('circle')

for (i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
  circle = circles[i]
  x = circle.dataset.xPos
  circle.setAttribute("cx", width * x)
}
```

error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'xPos' of undefined`

Comment: You can simply rename `data-xPos` to `data-xpos` in getAttribute and it will be work

Comment: @BobSponge so simple, thanks